# How can I specify two classes to a react-native component like 'View' or any other?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and want to add two classes to a single component, like `View` or `TouchableOpacity`. I have a button which goes to red or green when the user presses it...

Comment: Are you talking about styling on React Native with CSS?

Comment: no, through styleSheet

Comment: Can you add a code sample of what you're trying to do?

Comment: <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', paddingTop: 50, flex: 1 }} >
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bookContainer}>
                                <View>
                                    <Text>
                                        Book
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>

Comment: here i want to add two classes to touchableOpacity commponent one that set the border etc and other one that will set the backgroundColor to red when user is offline and green when user is online and blue when user presses it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, (assuming the `offline` and `buttonSelected` attributes are in your component state)

The general idea is to conditionally select the correct classes for on/offline and button unselected/selected.  Then you put those classes in the style array.  There are several ways to do what you want, this example is just one approach.

```
render()
{
    let offlineStyle = (this.state.offline)?styles.offline:styles.online;
    let activeStyle = (this.state.buttonSelected)?styles.active:styles.inactive;
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.general, offlineStyle, activeStyle]}>
                <Text>Book</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     );
 }

 ...
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      general: {
          borderWidth:1,
          borderColor:'gray'
      },
      online: {
          backgroundColor:'red'
      },
      offline: {
          backgroundColor:'green'
      },
      active: {
          backgroundColor:'blue'
      },
      inactive: {
      }
 });
```

Comment: IMHO you should point out the specific code and give a simple explanation rather than just posting the whole working code without any explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array to the style prop to apply multiple styles. When there is a conflict, the last one in the list takes precedence.

```
    import React, { Component`enter code here` } from 'react';

    import { View, Text, StyleSheet ,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

     red: {

     color: 'red'

    },
greenUnderline: {
    color: 'green',
    textDecoration: 'underline'
},
x:{

  },
y:{

}
big: {
    fontSize: 30
}


    });


    class Example extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>

    <TouchableOpacity style ={[stlyes.x , styles.y]}>
            <Text style={[styles.red, styles.big]}>Big red</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={[styles.red, styles.greenUnderline]}>Green 
    underline</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.greenUnderline, styles.red]}>Red underline</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.greenUnderline, styles.red, styles.big]}>Big red 
    underline</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.big, {color:'yellow'}]}>Big yellow</Text>
        </View>
    );

     }

    }
```

}